# How do I compute an eigenvector problem when it is underdetermined?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Find the eigenvectors of $$A =
>   \left[ {\begin{array}{ccc}
>    4 & 0 & 0 \\
>    -1 & 5 & -1 \\
>    -1 & 1 & 3
>   \end{array} } \right]$$

**Step 1.** Find the eigenvalues.

$$ \left| {\begin{array}{ccc}
   4-\lambda & 0 & 0 \\
   -1 & 5-\lambda & -1 \\
   -1 & 1 & 3-\lambda
  \end{array} } \right| = (4-\lambda)^3
$$

So the only eigenvalue is $\lambda = 4$, with multiplicity 3.

**Step 2.** The eigenvector for $\lambda = 4$ is

$$\left[ {\begin{array}{ccc}
   0 & 0 & 0 \\
   -1 & 1 & -1 \\
   -1 & 1 & -1
  \end{array} } \right]
\left[ {\begin{array}{c}
   a \\
   b \\
   c
  \end{array} } \right] = \left[ {\begin{array}{c}
   0 \\
   0 \\
   0
  \end{array} } \right]
$$

This gives the underdetermined equation system

$$\begin{align*} -a + b -c = 0\end{align*}$$

I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Have you heard of geometric and algebraic multiplicity and [*generalized eigenvectors*](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~moose/240S2013/slides7-31.pdf)? You need to find one generalized eigenvector in this problem. Also, https://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/math/MAT2440/v11/undervisningsmateriale/genvectors.pdf

Comment: @Moo I have heard of geometric and algebraic multiplicity but I don't understand how they allow me to solve this problem.

Comment: See the links I added.

Comment: How about [-1,0,1] and [1,1,0] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  have two free variables (say $b$ and $c$), so you'll get two linearly independent solutions.  For example, you may take $b=1$ and $c=0$ for one and $b=0$ and $c=1$ for the other.

Comment: You can take any values for $b$ and $c$ (not both $0$) and determine $a$ from the equation $-a+b-c=0$, then $(a,b,c)$ will be an eigenvector.  $b=1, c=0$ and $b=0, c=1$ are easy choices and will give you two linearly independent eigenvectors.  All the other eigenvectors are linear combinations of these.

Comment: Someone on Discord pointed out that my original comment was extremely insulting. I have deleted it but my vote is locked unless you edit your question one more time. Please edit your question and I will award you points.

Answer (score -1):

Answer to your question is $[1,2,1]^T$ which is the eigenvector for the eigenvalue 4

$-a+b-c=0 \Rightarrow b=a+c$ Put a=1 and c=1 you get b=2 (a and c are free variables)